# Matrix fields & flexslider

Tags: matrix, channel

I'm using the flexslider to create a carousel of pictures and use channel entries to populate the list items (images) that the flexslider uses to create the carousel.

Now I want to add a link to a pdf on al those list items that I have in a matrix field in the channel and that works also but only for the first list item.

Anybody nows why this is?

```
<div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
        {exp:channel:entries channel="lr_press"}
            {if press_slider_switch != ""}
            {press_artikel}
            <li><a href="{press_document}" targat="_blank"><img src="{press_beeld}" alt="{title}" /></a></li>
            {/press_artikel}
            {/if}
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What kind of field is "press_slider_switch"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggestion - but I would recommend having the markup for the slider inside your entries loop - that way if no results are returned, absolutely no slider markup winds up in the page template.  So like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="lr_press"}
    {if count == "1"}
    <div class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
    {/if}

    {exp:switchee variable="{press_slider_switch}" parse="inward"}
        {case value="on"}
             markup for ON items (so your matrix field, I believe)
        {/case}
        {case value="off"}
             markup for OFF items
        {/case}
    {/exp:switchee}     

    {if count == total_results}
        </ul>
    </div>
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

With regard to what's going on for each list item - if you describe in a bit more detail what "press_slider_switch" is - as a conditional wrapped around your list items, it can certainly have a big impact on what's generated for your slider - then I might be abel to assist further.

EDIT: Added switchee example to the markup above.  Also - one thing you might consider is using [Entry Type](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/entry-type) add-on in place of switch.  It has the same effect, really, except that it would allow you to hide/show your matrix field only for the switch values for which it is relevant - more for user-friendliness for the editor than anything - not much different in terms of the data or templating.

Comment: okaaay...never looked at it that way. Well first of all "press_slider_switch" is actually a P&T switch. To give some more info, in the back-end users can enter the following fields in the press channel: quote / image / document. The thing is that quote and image needs to be entered both or not because they belong together. To avoid creating complicated conditionals and fallbacks I thought I create a switch so the user can decide whether to use the quote and image and I only need to check whether the switch is set. That's why I approached it this way. But I'm a newb so... :D

Comment: A P&T switch field wouldn't be blank though, right? It would always have a state of either on or off? I haven't used one in a while, so i can't remember the specifics of the field setup.  But I would expect it not to be blank, and instead give you a yes/no, on/off state or something like that - which may be why your wrapping conditional isn't behaving as you expect.  The other thing you can do is install Croxton's Switchee add-on to use early-parsed switch case matching for your conditional. Great for performance and simplicity.  I've edited above to demonstrate a bit further.

Comment: Hey Jean thx for your suggestion. I checked the PT switch value and the OFF value was blank, that's why used the empty string to compare.
I followed your tip to use switchee and it did help so I guess it has to do with the parsing? Now I have to say that if I used a string value for ON and OFF my switchee didn't work but from the moment I used integer values 0 and 1 switchee did his work. Is this normal?

Comment: It should work with any value you specify - even a string, as Switchee offers Regex matching as well.

Comment: Strange do, juste did another test and switchee is still not evalutaing the PT switch value if set to string. But overall my problem is resolved, thanks for that Jean. I will do some more tests and if I can't find a solution I'll create a new post. Cheers and thx again!